# Maximum number of columns that PHP can fetch from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

What is the maximum number of columns that PHP can fetch from a MySQL database using mysqli?

I understand that in typical usage, you should never encounter this limit.

But also, this number should probably be documented somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking this question you are doing something wrong.

For a sanely designed database such a question shouldn't ever arise

Comment: I agree that no sanely designed database should encounter this limit. And I do not have such a database. Even so, is it not a fair question to ask? It is only when we know that the limit is high that we know it should never affect us.

Answer (score -1):

It is at least **4 million**, so it's unlikely you will be limited in this way in any normal scenario. You will probably hit other limits first.

---

I set up a test that built longer and longer queries like this:

```
SELECT "a","a","a","a","a","a" ...
```

I quickly ran out of memory.

I increased the memory_limit setting to 2048M, and successfully fetched 4 million columns.

When I tried 5 million, I got this error: `Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes.` The max_allowed_packet setting puts a size limit on the query you can send.

So even though a MySQL table is apparently limited to 4096 columns, your queries are not.

Comment: Well *individual* tables are limited to 4096 columns, but that's to say nothing of results from JOINs and computed columns. That said, PHP's internal limit is probably the max of whatever integer tracks column numbers in mysqlnd, and mysql's protocol limit is probably more complex to nail down as it seems to be subject to max_allowed_packet settings at least. All *that* said if you legitimately need millions of columns in a result set I would venture that you have other problems that you should look at solving first.

Comment: id this really a measure of columns or just memory?

Comment: @Dagon just memory really. I do not know if there is limit on the number of columns.